# How Jenkins internally set JAVA_HOME on Mac?

Tags: java, build, jenkins, osx-mountain-lion, java-home

I have interesting issue. Using Jenkins build master on Linux, and having one Mac Mountain Lion node (the thing described here works fine on Linuxes and Windows, but having problem only on this Mac machine, using both SSH connection and Java Web Start.

On client machine:

- I have installed JDK (and verified it).
- I set JAVA_HOME trough .profile for build user used for communication with Jenkins
- Java is accessible from shell, as well as Maven

but Jenkins always set another JAVA_HOME after starting the job ($JENKINS_HOME/tools/JDK/jdk1.6) but that folder is empty (on Linux nodes, inside this folder JDK should be deployed, and is, but not on Mac).

Does anyone know is it possible at all to change this behavior in Jenkins? Neither setting custom JAVA_HOME in Jenkins configuration didn't help, playing with .profile file, exporting variables on the fly in jobs, etc.

I'm using latest version 1.477

**Update & fix August 15th 2012**

So, there's one line when running the job on Mac, saying

*JDK installation skipped: Unknown CPU name: mac os x*

The point is that Oracle don't release JDK for Mac and this is kind of 'feature'.

Steps I did to fix this were:

- Configured SSH connection between Jenkins and Mac node
- Installed JDK manually to Mac
- Added to node configuration Java as a tool and specified path to JDK home on Mac node
- REMOVED Maven as tool from node configuration (as it's exported from Lion version already on the node, and if you don't remove it, your Maven stuff is going to fail for whatever clash reason).

This fixed the things on both Lion and Mountain Lion.

Comment: Please write your "update & fix" as an answer, so it will not hang as an unsolved question. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, did it. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

So, there's one line when running the job on Mac, saying

JDK installation skipped: Unknown CPU name: mac os x

The point is that Oracle don't release JDK for Mac and this is kind of 'feature'.

Steps I did to fix this were:

1. Configured SSH connection between Jenkins and Mac node
2. Installed JDK manually to Mac
3. Added to node configuration Java as a tool and specified path to JDK home on Mac node
4. REMOVED Maven as tool from node configuration
   (as it's exported from Lion version already on the node, and if you don't remove it,
   your Maven stuff is going to fail for whatever clash reason).

This fixed the things on both Lion and Mountain Lion.